# Hotel "rebooking" policy: full night's rate?

Tags: bookings, hotels

Is it normal for the fee for changing a booking in a hotel to be the whole of the room rate for the night?

I am booking for a one night stoppover a few months in advance, and am concerned about the moderately likely possibility of the airline changing the flight details in the mean time...

Comment: Most of the time when I make hotel reservations the standard terms seem to be that I can cancel 24 hours in advance and not be charged, but after that it costs one nightly rate. Though perhaps that's specific to the rough class of hotels I prefer to book.

Comment: Some hotel chains that I use allow cancellation up to 6PM of the night of the booking.  (Which annoyed one location when I went to cancel a booking and had to point out to them the terms of their own chain. ) So it is going to come down to the fine print of the hotel chain you are booking with - and that is something that we can't tell you about.

Comment: It can also depend on the rate itself. Some hotels have rates which are totally flexible and rates which are not modifiable, where a change then basically cost the whole cost as fee.

Comment: It depends where you book as well. It's not uncommon for some online hotel booking sites to list a price with a flexible cancellation policy and a lower one that's prepaid in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I book about 60 hotels a year, and typically *do* check the fine print. **Having to pay the first night if cancelled too late is quite typical.** If you only have one night, that is ugly, but it is better when you booked a week or more.

As others said, technically, cancel and change is typically the same for the hotel and follows the same charge rules; but they might be more willing to accomodate if you change.

Note that depending on the rate you book, you might have to pay *the whole stay* when you want to cancel (that’s what’s called ‘prepaid’) - therefore, you got a slightly cheaper price when booking. Others are slightly more expensive, and allow free cancellation until 6 pm the day.
You need to think about this when booking, not just pick the cheapest price.

Comment: Thanks - the fine print for the hotel in question doesn't talk about cancelling or changing "too late" ... it's anytime.  I later found out that they do have another rate which allows you to change or cancel.  It's about twice the inflexible rate, doh!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it normal for the fee for changing a booking in a hotel to be the
>   whole of the room rate for the night?

Depending on the hotel, it is normal for them to charge a fee - or not. Whether or not that fee is equivalent to a whole night's rate is up to the hotel. Your best bet would be to call them directly and explain your situation. Once they understand that you are **changing** your reservation and not **cancelling** it, then they might be more generous on waiving that fee.